# Displaying data is not possible in vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm sending this data to the view part that is written in view but isn't displayed, do you think?

```php
$itemsCount = DB::table('items')
    ->groupBy('level_id')
    ->selectRaw('level_id, count(*) as type');

$ItemsMdCount = DB::table('items')
    ->groupBy('project_model_id')
    ->selectRaw('project_model_id, count(*) as type');

return view('project.view',  compact('users', 'itemsCount', 'itemsMdCount'));
```

And in vue I make the display `{{ itemsCount }}`

How can I send the data to Vue.js and display it?

I tried and with an AJAX request but I do not realize how to properly use axios. I do not use much vue and I still have concerns, if you can give me a tip how I could display with the first option would be super cool.

```php
Route::get('/get-items-count-id/{modelId}', 'Ajax\AjaxController\getIemsCount')->name('getItemsCount');
Route::get('/get-items-md-count/{modelId}', 'Ajax\AjaxController\getItemsMdCount')->name('getItemsMdCount');

public function getItemsCount($modelId) 
{
    $itemsCount = Item::where('project_model_id', $modelId)
        ->groupBy('level_id')
        ->selectRaw('level_id, count(*) as type')->get();

    return $this->successResponse($itemsCount);
}
    
public function getItemsMdCount($modelId) 
{
    $itemsMdCount = Item::where('project_model_id', $modelId)
        ->groupBy('project_model_id')
        ->selectRaw('project_model_id, count(*) as type')->get(); 
 
    return $this->successResponse($itemsMdCount);                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to include axios.

Step 1: npm install --save axios

Step 2: Create a 'axios-auth.js' file and paste this code

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

export default instance
```

Step 3: Include import axios from './axios-auth' in store.js

Step 4: You can use vuex for API calls

Step 5: In the vuex Actions property you can call the API as shown below

```
signUp({ commit, dispatch }, authData) {
      return axios.post('/register', authData)
    }
```

Step 6: You can use

```
this.$store.dispatch('signUp', formData)
```

on the page from the API will be requested.

You can learn more about vuex here https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
itemsMdCount:[], 

getItemsCount() 
      {
        window.axios.get(`/get-items-md-count/${this.model.id}`).then(response({
          this:itemsMdCount = response.data.itemsMdCount
        }));
  },
```